# Wordpress query adding 0=1 in wp_query and result dissappear

Tags: wordpress

Wp query adding 0=1 in the query and results disappear, I am trying to adding multiple taxonomies in the query but it is producing 0=1. I am trying to fetch results from multiple taxonomies and in case of all I am passing a blank array to get all results

```
$category = array('');
    $post_regions = array('');
    $post_tag = array('');
    $post_categories = array('');
    if($_POST['pageType'] !== "all"){
        $category = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'terms' => explode(',', $_POST['pageType'])
            );
    }

    if($_POST['regions'] !== "default"){
        $post_regions = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_regions',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'IN',
                'terms' => explode(',', $_POST['regions'])
            );
    }
    if($_POST['topics'] !== "All"){
        $post_tag = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => explode(',', $_POST['topics']),
                'operator' =>'IN'
            );
    }


    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $dates
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', 
            $category,
            $post_regions,
            $post_tag,
            $post_categories,
        ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the empty array like this:

```
array();
```

If you define a array the way you do:

```
array('');
```

then array[0] is set.

Regards Tom

Comment: still same, I can still see 0=1

Comment: Ok. You changed all of them: $category, $post_regions, $post_tag, $post_categories ? And where is that $dates variable coming from and what is in there?

Comment: Date is coming fine

Comment: Now that the arrays are definded as empty, ... the answer of Steve Fan is very good and valid.

Answer (score 1):

Adding variable exists check outside arguments work for me:

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'publish_date',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'date_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $dates
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND'
        ),
);

if (isset($category))
    $args['tax_query'][] = $category;
    if (isset($post_regions))
    $args['tax_query'][] = $post_regions;
    if (isset($post_tag))
    $args['tax_query'][] = $post_tag;
    if (isset($post_categories))
    $args['tax_query'][] = $post_categories;

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `0=1` evaluates to `FALSE`, and your entire AND clause is discarded, leaving the entire expression to be relied on the value of the OR clause

Answer (score 0):

There is a block of code who design this SQL return.

In the class class-wp-query.php at line 2106

```
if ( ! $this->is_singular ) {
            $this->parse_tax_query( $q );

            $clauses = $this->tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

            $join  .= $clauses['join'];
            $where .= $clauses['where'];
        }
```

this return 0=1.... for me

Comment: Class class-wp-tax-query.php line 409. your prob is HERE !